# How to pause php loop processing and show a response then continue processing?

Tags: php, upload, response

I have have a foreach loop in an image/video uploading php script.I want to show a response right after the image uploading finished if the user uploads both videos and images simultaneously.(Using dropzone.js with parallel upload).how can i do this?Below I'm giving a rough structure of my code as it is quite large.

```
<?php
function getExtension($str)
{
    //Function for get extension of upload file array
}

$valid_img_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp","jpeg");
$valid_vid_formats = array("avi", "mp4", "flv", "vob");

if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") 
{
  count=0
  foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $name => $value)
  {  
   ...
   $ext = strtolower($ext);
   if(in_array($ext,$valid_img_formats))
    {
       if ( count( $_FILES['file']['name'] ) == $count ) 
             {
               //image moving to filesystem and showing response using database   
             }  
    }
    elseif(in_array($ext,$valid_vid_formats ))
    {
       if ( count( $_FILES['file']['name'] ) == $count ) 
             {
               //video moving to filesystem and showing response using database   
             }   
    }   
    else
    {
      echo "invalid file";
    }
  } 
} 
?>
```

I can get number of image files($img_count_sum ) in upload array using the code given below.I don't know how can i use it and does it make any sense?

```
$upload_array = $_FILES['file']['name'];    
$img_ext = implode('.', $upload_array);
$img_count_jpg = substr_count($img_ext, 'jpg');
$img_count_jpeg = substr_count($img_ext, 'jpeg');
$img_count_png = substr_count($img_ext, 'png');
$img_count_bmp = substr_count($img_ext, 'bmp');
$img_count_gif = substr_count($img_ext, 'gif');
$img_count_sum_array = array($img_count_jpg,$img_count_jpeg,$img_count_png,$img_count_bmp,$img_count_gif);
$img_count_sum = array_sum($img_count_sum_array);
```

Comment: I think HTTP response can only be done once per request-CMIIW. Use parallel AJAX request instead :)

Comment: Google `PHP output buffering`

Comment: @Hanky Yeah I've read about ob_start() and ob_flush().Can you please show me how to use it?Thanks...